# Use jQuery attr to scroll to data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how I would use this method:

```
$('[data-jump-spy]').each(function(){
     var dataObj = .data('jump-spy');
     $(this).onclick ({
              scrollTop: $("#" + dataObj ).offset().top();
     });
});
```

to attach it to a link like so:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-jump-spy="divContentThatsFarDownPage">Who we are</a>
....
....
....
....
<div class="box radius box-grey --animate" id="divContentThatsFarDownPage">
    ....
</div>
```

> Final Solution can be found below

This function will allow you to code your website more easily. Simply type `<div class="whatever iconArrow-to-Content LinkText-to-Content Img-to-Content" data-jump-spy="page-content"`

```
$('[data-jump-spy]').each(function(){
    var dataObj = $(this).data('jump-spy');
    $(this).click(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $("#" + dataObj ).offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Use `.click()` not `.onclick()`

Comment: What is `” .data()"`?

Comment: I was wondering about the point of dataObj, being the same as this. Of course it's not... just the var name confused me. dataObj is a STRING. Also, what if the target only has a class? Then you'd better be of by putting # or . inside your data, and take it out of the scrolltop line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of changes

```
$('[data-jump-spy]').each(function(){
     var dataObj = $(this).data('jump-spy'); // needs $(this) at beginning since .data needs to run on some object
     $(this).click(function(){ // used click instead of onclick and you need to pass a function as an argument
              $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#" + dataObj ).offset().top}); // use .top instead of .top() as it is a property and not a method
     });
});
```

Comment: @RBStudios missed that. it needs to be `.top` and not `.top()` as it is just a property and not a method. Use the [documentation of jquery](https://api.jquery.com/), it is very detailed.

Comment: @RBStudios, looks like you were missing more stuff. Like where to apply the `scrollTop`. updated the code.